# Published an npm but its nowhere to be seen on the internet

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I just published an npm while following the procedure and it is found as published on https://www.npmjs.com/ also.

Like -

[image: npm package]

However, I am unable to find it on the internet when I search it.

Comment: You'll have to wait a bit longer than 3 minutes.

Comment: Can you elaborate. What do you mean by  search in internet? From the screen shot it's published

Comment: @nithin. Yes. But when I search it in google, it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all the packages you publish come to the top of google search results.

Google searches the results across a wide range of content across internet. Not just npm registry.The search results are based on the relevance of search term with content across the internet. Results from other websites may also pop up.

It can also depend on popularity(usage) of the package and other criteria which I'm not aware of. Since you have published the package recently, google won't be even aware of it. Next time when the google crawlers crawl npmjs they might see the package(May be its possible that npm registry might have custom feed pushing to google depending on package usage rather than google crawlers crawl them) .

So don't worry if it doesn't appear in google search. Your package can be searched from npmjs and is available for all to use, and can be shared with everyone. May be eventually you reach the top of google search results :)

Also you can add relevant `description`,  `keywords` to your `package.json` that so that people can find it easily in npm registry search. Right now it shows up only if its an exact package name match.